# To which day is a nightshift attributed?

Tags: germany, work-time, overtime

Suppose one works the nightshift from Tuesday 10 PM to Wednesday 6 AM.

Would this be considered Tuesdays work or Wednesdays work?

Is the nightshift attributed to the day it starts, or to the day it ends?

Same question for registering overtime. If my shift ends at 6 AM, but I do two hours of overtime, is that the first day's overtime, because the shift started on that day, or the next days overtime, because that is when it actually too place?

Is this codified by law? Are there regulations? Or can every company make their own rules about this?

Comment: What's the issue? Possible overtime? The starting time of the next shift?

Comment: One of the two US companies I worked that ran 3 shifts had it as 3rd shift on the start day, the second as first shift on the end day.  I don't think there's any standard here, countries that have a weekend legally codified in labor law might be different.

Comment: Ask your employer?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question seems valid as it varies by region and  law. Probably could be specific to location or better asked on law

Comment: @coll: I find the question not very clear. OP asks bunch of loosely related questions, answers to which might be different depending background that is missing. What is their actual problem?

Comment: In the US, it completely depends on the company. I know one that restarts the clock at 4 AM (meaning it's considered the previous day until 3:59 AM) and I know another one that restarts the clock at 5 AM. In other words, you have to read your employee manual (or just call HR, this is a question for them, not us). But if this is a question about overtime, there are other rules that could come into play if your shift crosses that boundary. In that case, check the regulations on overtime and wages on the labor department/ministry for your state/country for the type of job you have.

Comment: @coll The downvotes are there because we need to understand the context. Is this for tax reasons? Is this for contractual reasons?

Comment: In your example, what's wrong with having Tuesday: 2:00; Wednesday: 8:00; Thursday: 6:15?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: There is no further context. No tax reasons, no contractual reasons. It just is what it is: I want to attribute a nightshift to a day and am not sure wether to choose the starting or the ending day.

Comment: @Kichi: Interesting idea. I don't like it though. I want to attribute the hole shift as it is to a day.

Comment: @J.Doe: The questions aren't "loosely related". They're the same question, asked a little differently in the hope to make the issue more clear. Sorry I've lost you there. There is no further background. The actual problem is exactly what the question asks: To which day should I attribute a nightshift?

Comment: @user1785730 Choose whatever day you want, just be consistent.

Comment: @user1785730: When speaking colloquially, nights shifts get referred by their starting day. If you want to be precise, you might say _night from Tuesday to Wednesday_ or something, but that is rather mouthful. If i wanted to write table of shifts to hand out people, i would create simple calendar in excel, where night shifts would span multiple days.

Comment: @user1785730 You mention that you "want to attribute a nightshift to a day and am not sure wether to choose the starting or the ending day." We are asking about context because we want to know why. Since you mention that there is no further context, are you just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: @zmike: I want to register overtime. The overtime has to be attributed to a date. In case the workshift spans the night, I was unsure to which date people would expect the overtime to be attributed.

Answer (score 3):

Everywhere I'm aware of they count nightshift as the day on which it starts. But I haven't heard of that being a law of any sort (I'm not a lawyer).

The regulated bit is just the hours worked, not which day unless it crosses into a weekend or other time frame which is paid differently in some locales. If in doubt ask HR.

When I did factory work Friday nightshift started 10PM Friday and ended 6AM Saturday. But due to the locale I got paid normal nightshift rate from 10PM to midnight and time and a half for the 6 hours on Saturday morning.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, just as valid as any other system. plus 1.